# Bootstrap4 nav-item issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I am movig a project from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4...

the following code was working fine w Bootstrap 3 , but it's not with Bootstrap 3...

here is the [jsFiddle test](https://jsfiddle.net/erwin16/xgpmn2kz/) and the html code

Boostrap3 behavior :
initial button 1 is active
when the user click on one of the 3 buttons, it displays the corresponding tab. And the button is raised up, the other buttons stay down.

Boostrap 4 behavior :
initial button 1 is active
when the user click on one of the 3 buttons, it displays the corresponding tab. And the button is raised up, the other buttons never go down.. they stay active...

```
<section id="memberships" class="memberships">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 text-center">
                <h2 class="header-text">TEST</h2>
                <div class="memberships-mockup">
                    <div id="nav-tabContent" class="tab-content">
                        <div id="nav-first" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-first-tab" class="tab-pane fade show active"><p>1111111111</p></div>
                        <div id="nav-second" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-second-tab" class="tab-pane fade"><p>2222222222</p></div>
                        <div id="nav-third" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-third-tab" class="tab-pane fade"><p>3333333333</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="myTab" role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sd-4">
                    <a id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item nav-link active"><span class="number">1</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sd-4">
                    <a id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-second" class="nav-item nav-link"><span class="number">2</span></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sd-4">
                    <a id="nav-third-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-third" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-third" class="nav-item nav-link"><span class="number">3</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `nav-tabs` behavior to work properly in Bootstrap 4, each `tab` should be a direct sibling, not in separate columns.

https://www.codeply.com/go/Wu5OKQvDiQ

```
<div id="myTab" role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <a id="nav-first-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-first" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-first" aria-expanded="true" class="nav-item nav-link active"><span class="number">1</span></a>
        <a id="nav-second-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-second" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-second" class="nav-item nav-link"><span class="number">2</span></a>
        <a id="nav-third-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-third" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-third" class="nav-item nav-link"><span class="number">3</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I did not check that ... as my code was running fine with Bootstrap4-beta-3 ... I guess it changed in between ...

Comment: The spacing of the nav-tabs in the row is now based on the <a> padding ... not anymore on columns... is that right ?

Comment: Yes, you're padding is overridden by `section.memberships .nav-tabs a`

Comment: My concern is how I can center the bunh ( all 3 <a> ) in the row ...  as I used the cilumn to do it

Comment: Got it ... if I want to justify the all bunch of 3  <a> cards I need to put the div tablist inside a row   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center"> ...